# How can I import a rigged model(Facial controls included) from SFM to blender?

Tags: animation, armature, import

Decompiling from Crowbar and using Source Tools, I got a the model into blender, and using nodes assigned the textures, but no matter what I try I get one of two outcomes,

-the model is imported with no bones

-the model is imported and the bones are visible, but they don't move the model when used.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Attached:List of files received after decompiling via crowbar

[image: files after decompiling via Crowbar]

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting it from the external application into a format Blender supports such as:
.dae
.abc
.fbx
.bvh
.ply
.obj
.stl
.svg
.glb/.gltf

Then in Blender: Go to File, Import - select the matching format, locate & import the file.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do that, all I have is the decompiled .mdl file

Answer (score 0):

[Blender Source Tools](http://steamreview.org/BlenderSourceTools/) should allow you to import the format into Blender. for 2.79 prior you can find an older version on the site's "Release Archives".